# Difference between const constructor and cost?

Tags: dart

I have the following code snippet:

```
class ImmutablePoint {

  final double x, y;

  const ImmutablePoint(this.x, this.y);
}

void main() {
  
  var i = const ImmutablePoint(4,6);
  print(i.x);
  
}
```

As you can see, a `const constructor` is defined in the class. However, what is the difference between `const` and `const constructor`?

What is the difference when I change from `var i = const ImmutablePoint(4,6);` to `var i = ImmutablePoint(4,6);`?

The point is, sometimes I see in flutter example `const Text("FFF")`, although a `const constructor` is already defined for the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class with a const constructor only *allows* you to create const instances of that class, but it does not make all instances const.

That is controlled at the constructor invocation site - the const constructor is only used within a const context. A const context is basically inferred by any preceding`const` keyword, the following all would use the const constructor:

```
var foo = const ImmutablePoint(1,2);
const foo = ImmutablePoint(1,2);
var foos = const [ImmutablePoint(1,2)];
```

But the following would not, as it is not in a const context:

```
var foo = ImmutablePoint(1,2);
```

Comment: What kind of constructor does `var foo = ImmutablePoint(1,2);` use? In the `ImmutablePoint` class, only `const constructor` is defined. There is no any option than `const constructor`

Comment: I don't know exactly how the dart language specification defines this, but its the same constructor essentially. You can think of any const constructor as actually defining both a const and identical non-const constructor. There is probably only really one constructor under the covers but I don't know the specifics.

Comment: When you write `const ImmutablePoint(1, 2)`, the language specifies that it creates a new object, just like `new ImmutablePoint(1, 2)`, and then it checks whether there is already another `ImmutablePoint` object with the *exact same state* created by another `const` invocation, and if so, it returns that object instead of the new object . This gives *canonicalization*. It makes sense because other constraints also ensure that the object is deeply immutable. You can still do `new ImmutablePoint(1, 2)`, and it does the same thing, just without the following canonicalization.